# Counting lines in a text file; use result to split text files into sections

Tags: batch-file

Using Windows batch or possibly another language I am looking to split a text file containing 85K+ results into separate text files. There is also a header at the top that needs to be present on every new text file.

The short but only code I have and can get to work is as follows;

```
FIND "" /v /c /n "D:\Users\ashley.fayers\Desktop\M6_040615\M6_040615_B_FULL\M6_040615_B.txt"
```

This code provides me with the number of lines in the text but it also includes the header which I need to not include. But I need to include it in the later created text files.

Comment: it's not DOS, but Windows, isn't it? could you please provide some examples of the desired output? what is the separator condition? can you tell us what you have tried beyond the FIND?

Comment: Nothing else I've tried has produced results...Yeah, I'm just running the cmd.exe and entering the coed sorry; busy day at work. :')

Comment: It's going to be a pretty standard shape for a batch file - `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`, a `for /f %%a in (file.txt) do ( ... )` line iteration loop, probably a `set /A J="J+1"` line counter, maybe one loop to count and another to process, an `echo "header info" > file!J!.txt` and an `echo %%a >> file!J!.txt` kind of commands. But what do you mean *split it into separate files* - do you want 85,000 files named file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt, or what?

Comment: Assuming you can better specify your requirements, this could be done with batch provided each line is <8k. But it would be needlessly complex and slow. Better to use a different scripting language like PowerShell, VBS, or JScript.

Comment: Separate the 85K+ in parts based on what? A maximum number of lines? A number of files?

Comment: Seperate it into 5K sections.

Comment: 5K bytes or 5K lines? My solution below separate the file in N number of _lines_!

Comment: 5,000 lines of text; however you appear to have answered my question below. It's just the header now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: *Number of header lines added*

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "theFile=D:\Users\ashley.fayers\Desktop\M6_040615\M6_040615_B_FULL\M6_040615_B.txt"
set headerLines=25

for /F %%a in ('find /C /V "" ^< "%theFile%"') do set /A totalLines=%%a-headerLines
call :SplitFile < "%theFile%"
goto :EOF


rem Split the file in parts 10,000 lines each

:SplitFile

for /L %%i in (1,1,%headerLines%) do set /P header[%%i]=
set /A part=0, numLines=10000

:nextPart
   set /A part+=1
   if %totalLines% lss %numLines% set numLines=%totalLines%
   (
      for /L %%i in (1,1,%headerLines%) do echo(!header[%%i]!
      for /L %%i in (1,1,%numLines%) do (
         set "line="
         set /P line=
         echo(!line!
      )
   ) > Part%part%.txt
   set /A totalLines-=numLines
if %totalLines% gtr 0 goto nextPart
exit /B
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you. one thing is I need to change the amount of lines used for the header; which value is that? The header is 25 lines long....

Comment: Done! **`;-)`**  This is the type of details that you should include since the very beginning! **`:|`**

Comment: Yeah sorry, very stressful day today. Forgetting everything. :')

Comment: Oh sorry, just ran it and it says Echo Off on three lines but I can't add anything onto these text files, they are used for processing my other files.

Comment: If the error was in a _header line_, then I just fixed it (I added the left parentheses in `echo(!header[%%i]!` part)